# c# function for filling ComboBox

Tags: c#

I Want to create a function in ClassProducts.cs file and when I call that function it should return Values & Tags for that ComboBox.

ComboBox Control is in ViewProducts Form and function in ClassProducts.cs class. Function accepts 1 parameter called Cat_ID

```
class ClassProducts
{

    public DataTable FillSubCats(int catID)
        {
            DataTable items = new DataTable();

            SqlCommand cmdFillSubCatL1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblProductCategories WHERE Cat_ParentCat =" + catID, con);

            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader sda = cmdFillSubCatL1.ExecuteReader();
            while (sda.Read())
            {
                ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
                item.Text = (sda["Cat_Name"]).ToString();
                item.Value = (sda["Cat_ID"]).ToString();

                items.Load(sda);
            }
            sda.Dispose();
            sda.Close();
            con.Close();

            return items;
        }
}
```

I want a function in ClassProducts file which will be filling ComboBoxes in ViewProducts.cs Form. Whenever function called it should return combo box items to the calling file.

I have tried this function but it is not working.

Please help.
Thank You.

Comment: *but it is not returning as I'm expecting* what is it returning and what you were expected?

Comment: Sorry about that... I wanted to say that it is not working at all.

Comment: Is this application WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @ThomasN it's WinForms application.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably due to the fact that you are not using `sqlparameters`. `Cat_ParentCat` must be an `int` field so when you try to use query with string concatenation, a cats to  `nvarchar` field is taking place, and since you don't wrap `catId` with quotes on your query,  it fails . In any case using SQL Parameters,  will also help you avoid SQL injection. Try:

```
SqlCommand cmdFillSubCatL1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblProductCategories WHERE Cat_ParentCat =@catId", con);
cmdFillSubCatL1.Parameteres.Add("@catId",SqlDbType.Int).Value=catId;
...
```

**EDIT:**
After Correct comment, a better query should be:

```
"SELECT  Cat_Name,Cat_ID FROM tblProductCategories WHERE Cat_ParentCat =@catId"
```

Finally since you want to load a `DataTable` don't use Datareader but a dataAdapter:

```
...  
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = cmdFillSubCatL1 ;
adapter.Fill(items );
```

Comment: This won't address the exact question(question is not clear as well). It's only a partial tip to improve his code. I mention partial because, In this case he needs only two fields, then why are you suggesting him to get all items using `*` ?

Comment: It causes error near while loop: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: @PrathameshRaut, this is where you should do some debugging. Check the result set of your slq data reader.

Comment: @sujithkarivelil That table haves only 4 colums in it, so i'm requesting all of them.

Comment: It still gives me an errorAn unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.  I have added a method FillSubCatsProxy which should simulate what your method is returning.:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    comboBox1.DataSource = FillSubCatsProxy(1);
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Cat_Name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Cat_ID";
    comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, e) => { MessageBox.Show("Selected:" + comboBox1.SelectedValue); };
}

public DataTable FillSubCatsProxy(int catID)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Cat_Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Cat_ID");

    dt.Rows.Add("Fish","1");
    dt.Rows.Add("Jack","2");
    return dt;
}

public DataTable FillSubCats(int catID)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Somewhere");

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        DataTable items = new DataTable();

        var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Cat_Name,Cat_ID FROM tblProductCategories WHERE Cat_ParentCat = " + catID, con);
        da.Fill(items);

        return items;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
}
```